# The argument type 'TextStyle?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I am getting this error...

code snippet that is throwing this error:

```
catalog.desc.text.textStyle(context.captionStyle).make(),
```

Comment: This is an error of null aware operator.

Comment: check https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `context.captionStyle` has the `TextStyle?` type, which means it can be `null`. The `.textStyle()` function only accepts `TextStyle` objects, hence the error.

You either have to make sure that `context.captionStyle` is not `null` before trying to pass it to `.textStyle()`, or assuring the compiler it will never be `null` by writing `.textStyle(context.captionStyle!)` (but you will still get an error if it becomes `null` somehow).